# Pesquisar nome pelo primeiro e último nome

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em elaborar uma *query* MySQL para pesquisar um nome, sendo que a pessoa possa digitar o primeiro e o último nome e aceitar ter outro nome entre eles. Por exemplo:

Pesquisa: 'JOSÉ NUNES' ou 'NUNES JOSÉ'

Resultado: JOSÉ SILVA NUNES

Do jeito que pesquiso hoje é basicamente:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE nome LIKE %pesquisa%
```

Li algo sobre REGEXP, mas não consegui usar funcionalmente e não queria ficar repetindo vários "`AND WHERE nome LIKE...`" pois uso PDO, então complica um pouco.

Comment: A coluna `nome` armazena o nome completo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui usando RLIKE, assim:

> SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE nome RLIKE '(?=.*Silva)(?=.*Jose)'

assim não importa a ordem, nem se tem algo entre eles :D

Comment: e se o usuário digitar 3 nomes ?

Comment: na verdade, o que eu fiz no código foi usar um foreach dando explode no nome:   $nomeSeparado = explode(" ", $nome);
        $sqlNome = "";

        foreach ($nomeSeparado as $n){
            $sqlNome .= "(?=.*".$n.")";
        }

Comment: ham bem rsrs...blz parabéns.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE nome LIKE %$nome%$sobrenome%
```

Supondo que tenha campos separados para o nome e sobrenome

Answer (score 0):

Tente dar um replace nos espaços, substituindo pelo coringa:

php:

```
 str_replace (' ' , '%' , $pesquisa )
```

mysql

```
REPLACE(pesquisa,' ','%')
```

**Edição:**

utilize o comando RLIKE, porém este pode retornar registros indesejados. Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE nome RLIKE REPLACE('JOSÉ NUNES',' ','|')
```

Essa consulta retornará o equivalente a:

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE nome LIKE %JOSE% OR nome LIKE %NUNES%
```

Comment: eu acabei de tentar isso, mas caso eu pesquise primeiro o sobrenome da pessoa, e depois o nome, não me sai nenhum resultado. Queria algum resultado semelhante de quando uso vários AND nome LIKE ...

Comment: consegue trabalhar com arrays, dando um split na variavel pesquisa onde houver espaços ?

Comment: Consigo sim, da p fazer exploit

Comment: e consegue montar a string da query em um loop no php ?

Comment: consigo, mas a dificuldade de colocar os AND nome LIKE... é que eu uso PDO, ai eu tenho um bindValue pra substituir um ":nome" dentro da query, entende?

Comment: consegui! olha o minha resposta abaixo :)